# Three.js the model is abnormally large

Tags: three.js, gltf

Add the GLTF model into the scene, traverse the node, add a water surface map, and the water is abnormal

```
 gltf.scene.traverse((node) => {
            if (node.name == "CNC-water") {
              const water = new Water(node.geometry, {
                scale: 2,
                textureWidth: 1024,
                textureHeiht: 1024,
                color: 0x6495ed,
                reflectivity: 0.3,
                normalMap0: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("../src/assets/water/Water_1_M_Normal.jpg"),
                normalMap1: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("../src/assets/water/Water_2_M_Normal.jpg"),
              });
              scene.add(water);
              objects.push(water)
            }
})
```

After that, the size of "CNC-water" is normal, but the "water" becomes very large
[The red interior is the building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QuV7.png)

Comment: It'll be difficult to exactly see why the scale is different without having the gltf model. Is it possible that the parent of "CNC-water" has a scale which is removed on adding it to scene? You could console log the scale before and after adding to scene and check the difference? https://threejs.org/docs/?q=objec#api/en/core/Object3D.getWorldScale

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.